# Angular2 ngForm not working

Tags: forms, angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I am trying to do a login form component but I cannot read the form data.

When I try to write username on the console, *'undefined'* writes.

Everything seems usual but form data does not come to component.

Below is the html code:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm)"
      #myForm="ngForm"
      class="form-signin">
    <div class="form-group">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
        <input type="text"
               id="inputUsername"
               name="inputUsername"
               class="form-control"
               placeholder="User Name"
               required>
        <input type="password"
               id="inputPassword"
               name="inputPassword"
               class="form-control"
               placeholder="Password" >
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
            type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Component ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'signin',
    templateUrl: './signin.component.html',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class SigninComponent implements OnInit{
    constructor(){}

    ngOnInit(){ }

    onSubmit(form: NgForm){
        console.log(form.value.inputUsername);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think the styles are relevant to the problem :D

Comment: Ok, I deleted styles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add the `ngModel` directive to each of the form fields. This registers the form fields to your form.

```
    <input type="text"
           id="inputUsername"
           name="inputUsername"
           class="form-control"
           placeholder="User Name"
           ngModel
           required>
```

Comment: I am a newbie on Angular2 and I did not know this requirement. Thank you, this is the right answer.

Comment: You are welcome! Here are some further readings https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgForm-directive.html

Answer (score 0):

add FormsModule in appmodule.ts

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

imports: [
FormsModule,
]

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.